# AVR assembly: load a 16 bit number into two 8 bit registers

Tags: assembly, avr

I am completely new to AVR assembly and I have a hex number `0x20C` which is 16 bit.

I want to load this constant hex number in two 8 bit registers in AVR assembly

Is it possible to do something like:

```
LDI R17:R18 0x20C
```

EDIT: if it is not possible to load a 16 bit number in two 8 bit registers this way, may someone could give me an alternative option?

Comment: updated my answer with examples for immediates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few instructions to do 16-bit addition or increment with pairs of registers, but not loads from memory and certainly not immediates.  **You need to load each byte separately**, using one `ld`/`ldi`/`ldd`/`lds`/whatever instruction for each byte / each destination register.

(There is an instruction to copy a pair of registers to another pair, upported on many modern AVR CPUs, (see [@ReAl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340885/avr-assembly-load-a-16-bit-number-into-two-8-bit-registers/53350940#53350940)), but not load or load-immediate.  You can make a macro for 2 instructions as ReAl shows, but it won't improve performance or code-size, just human readability.

---

AVR is a RISC instruction-set where most (almost all?) whole instructions are 16-bit.  There isn't room for a 16-bit immediate, only 8.  **You can always split an immediate into its two 8-bit halves, like `ldi r17, 0x0c` for the low half and `ldi r18, 0x2` for the high half.**

I checked the AVR instruction set and didn't see any multi-byte loads or immediates (https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/index.html - update; the online ISA ref is much less nicely formatted than it used to be).

Then I compiled this C with AVR gcc [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+return_immediate(void)+%7B+return+0x20c%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+glob%3B%0Aint+return_global(void)+%7B%0A++++return+glob%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+add(int+*a,+int+*b)+%7B%0A++++return+*a+%2B+*b%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:32.3899878518724,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:avrg464,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'AVR+gcc+4.6.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.15727779057957,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:avrg464,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-mmcu%3Davr6',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'AVR+gcc+4.6.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.45273435754805,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to see if maybe there was something I was missing.

```
int return_immediate(void) { return 0x20c; }

    ldi r24,lo8(524)    # ldi r24, 0x0c
    ldi r25,hi8(524)    # ldi r25, 0x02
    ret


int glob;
int return_global(void) {
    return glob;
}

    lds r24,glob
    lds r25,glob+1
    ret


int add(int *a, int *b) {
    return *a + *b;
}

    mov r30,r24
    mov r31,r25   Z = a
    ld r24,Z
    ldd r25,Z+1   retval = *a
    mov r30,r22
    mov r31,r23   Z = b
    ld r18,Z
    ldd r19,Z+1   tmp = *b
    add r24,r18
    adc r25,r19   retval += tmp
    ret
```

So unless AVR gcc has a missed optimization, or there's some reason it's avoiding a word load, you can't do it.

Update: gcc is targeting baseline AVR, so it can't use `movw` to copy a pair of registers.

Compiling with `-mmcu=avr6` makes `add(int*, int*)` more efficient:

```
add:
    movw r30,r24   # Z = a
    ld r24,Z
    ldd r25,Z+1
    movw r30,r22   # Z = b
    ld r18,Z
    ldd r19,Z+1
    add r24,r18
    adc r25,r19
    ret
```

But as we can see, there's still no instruction for doing anything else to a pair of registers, so it all has to be done separately.  Still, copying a pair of registers with one machine instruction is quite nice because it's not rare to need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Peter Cordes answer, AVR instruction set has no instruction for loading 16 bit value  into register pair. But…

> if it is not possible to load a 16 bit number in two 8 bit registers
>   this way, may someone could give me an alternative option?

For your convenience assembler usually has ability to create macro (рay attention to this opportunity if you plan to program a lot in assembly).

Macro syntax depend on toolchain. For `gnu as` I use following macro that loads 16-bit immediate value into given and next register

```
.macro ldi_w reg:req, val:req
    ldi \reg, lo8(\val)
    ldi \reg + 1, hi8(\val)
.endm
```

So

```
ldi_w   r16, 0xBEEF
```

loads `0xEF` into `r16` and `0xBE` into `r17`.

**Important note:** `gnu as` allows to use register numbers (`ldi 16, 0xC3`) as well as register names (`ldi r16, 0xC3`). The macro above requires register *numbers*, so that all my assembler sources includes `avr_reg_numbers.h` that contains defines like

```
#ifdef r0
#undef r0
#endif
#define r0 0
```

Using this style macros the example from Peter Cordes answr can be rewrited as

```
mov_w r30, r24 ; r30 ← r24, r31 ← r25
ld_w  r24, Z
mov_w r30, r22
ld_w  r18, Z
add_w r24, r18
```

p.s.0 My `avr_as_macro.h` contains a lot of macro like `lds_w`, `sts_w`, `push_w`, …, `ror_w` and so on. Most of them generated by other macroassembler commands. For example, `asr_w`, `lsr_w` and `ror_w` generated by

```
//----------------------------    right word shifts
// asr_w, lsr_w, ror_w
.irp cmd, asr, lsr, ror
    .macro \cmd\()_w reg:req
        \cmd \reg+1  $  ror \reg
    .endm
.endr
```

p.s.1 Some of AVR chips have assembly instruction `movw` that moves register pair in one cpu cycle, some of them (old or very simple) has no such command. So I use macro `mov_w` that invokes `movw` or generates a pair of commands depend on current AVR arch level.

```
//----------------------------------    word move
// movw exist in all new AVRs except __AVR_TINY__ (tiny4..10/20/40)
// Not exist in tiny26
// odd register numbers and overlapping are not supported
#ifdef __AVR_HAVE_MOVW__
.macro  mov_w   dst:req, src:req
    movw    \dst, \src
.endm
#else
.macro  mov_w   dst:req, src:req
    mov \dst, \src  $  mov \dst+1, \src+1
.endm
#endif
```

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't know there were extensions to the AVR ISA.  I updated my answer for that, and to point to yours for the macro, that's some nice macro trickery.

Comment: @PeterCordes Beside `movw` the only word instructions in AVR is `adiw`/`sbiw` which add/substract immediate value in range 0..63 to/from one of register pairs `r25,r24`, `r27,r26` (`X` pointer), `r29,r28` (`Y` pointer) and `r31,r30` (`Z` pointer). (`adiw r24, 0` can be used as "is `r25,r24`pair contains zero)